# What is the impact of the upcoming GCP OAuth consent change on user access to our app?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, scopes

Recently we received an mail saying that our app may be impacted by an upcoming change in GCP, which would have prevented at least one user from accessing our app in the past month.

It says that our application is using the user's credentials to call GCP APIs, and saying that we can modify our application to preserve access for all users by updating your application’s OAuth consent to remove its use of the cloud-platform OAuth scope or any other GCP scopes you may depend on. It also says that our application may still use GCP by leveraging service account authentication flows.

Finally it says that this new enforcement will begin rolling out June 30, 2023. We would like to know what the mentioned GCP scopes are and the impact on this.

Does anyone know the information about this notification?

I have tried to search the announcement for this, but nothing found so far. I also checked the app verification page and it looks like everything works fine with green check on each of the restricted / sensitive scopes.

We expect that there exists at least some annoucement on what scopes we are using should be removed , or how we can proceed on this issue.

Comment: do you have a link to what change they are taking about

Comment: No, they did not provide link about the annoucement. They only provide the links for [modifying the user consent](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/configure-oauth-consent#configure_oauth_consent_register_your_app), and the [service account auth flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account).

Comment: any change you want to share the scopes you are using and the authorization code?

Comment: We did not change the scopes we are using for a long time. Here are the scopes we used in the consent setting page (https://imgur.com/CKnMCnY).

Comment: Any chance you can give me a full screen shot of the message you got and i can check with the team.  It could be that this is just a form email that gets sent to anyone detected GCP.   I may be able to find out what scopes are effected exactly if i know which email you got.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :D  This is the full screen shot of the message we got: (https://imgur.com/cRPXFZD).

Comment: okay let me send it off to see if I can get some more information

Comment: The team is looking into it

Comment: Thank you for the help. Please let us know if there's any updates.

Answer (score 3):

Google is applying changes that more tightly enforce policies around cloud-platform usage. These policies prevent users from calling GCP through OAuth when their access to GCP is restricted.

We're recommending that developers migrate to using [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) when calling GCP APIs so that the service account is initiating the request rather than the end user of your application.

Comment: This answer is what I have been told by Google internally. Do you have an opinion on OAuth user credentials impersonating a service account to make requests? This removes the requirement to distribute service account JSON keys. I wrote an [article](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-improving-security-with-impersonation/) on impersonation, maybe it is time to update the article.

Comment: A user who is restricted from GCP is generally unable to impersonate a service account. The user's credentials cannot be used to call the [generateAccessToken API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/generateAccessToken) for generating a service account credential. The user wouldn't experience a change in behavior if the application generates a credential on the user's behalf (without relying on the user's credential having permission to impersonate the service account).

Comment: Max, what do you mean by "A user who is restricted from GCP"? do you mean a user that does not have GCP IAM permissions? In that case, they would not have the permissions required to impersonate. Or do you mean a user that Google has restricted due to some violation? I answer a lot of Google Cloud IAM and Auth questions, so I want to make sure I am current with every detail.

Comment: I am specifically referring to use of GCP restricted by Google, unrelated to the user's IAM permission grants.

Comment: Max, I still do not understand your choice of the words `use of GCP restricted by Google`. Perhaps providing an example and context will help me understand what you mean. I understand Google OAuth, IAM, security, etc very well and your words are a mystery to me.

Comment: Google may disable a user account's access to GCP. This can be necessary in cases of abuse or due to violation of GCP's terms. The enforcement is applied through Google's internal systems and is not overridable by a project/organization owner. In cases where a user has their access to GCP disabled, the user should be unable to call the generateAccessToken API.